# css background-size fail as well as image position

Tags: html, css

Alright, for my site users/members have an option to upload/link a custom image to use for the start page of my site. This works well with nearly all new browsers that support background-size. But does not fill in the entire div section with the image if the browser does not support css3 background-size.

Yesterday I had a chance to test my site on a 25"inch monitor and ended up realizing the image display part failed. What ended up happening is that the image was shifted to the left.

Today checking the code I forgot that I had this line in "background-position: top left;" but I remembered why I left it in the code, the moment I add "top center" or just "top" the background is still displayed however there is like 6 - 10 px white gab to the left of it. I tried using left: 0px; but can't get it to work since I am using position: fixed; and if I change it to position: absolute it displays full image which ends up creating a scroll bar on the bottom.

Here is the code for the CSS part I am using at the moment

```
#cpBackgroundImg  { 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-clip: border-box;
background-origin: padding-box; 
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: top left;
position:fixed;
z-index:-10;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
background-size:100%;
}
```

and here is the other part of the code which actually displays the image

```
<div style="display: block; opacity: 0.99999; width: 1600px; height: auto; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; background-image: url(<?php echo base64_decode($_COOKIE['phx_utmc_session']); ?>);" id="cpBackgroundImg"></div>
```

Can some one tell me how to fix this problem?
- Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/Hnwjg/6/

Comment: add a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of this it will be easier to see what is the problem

Comment: You could use the background-position with a % value such as 50% 50%.

Comment: That is too long a fiddle mate. Please post only the concerning markup with out the head and the CSS and Javascript in their appropiate section! From your fiddle, atleast, I can't say where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 1600px;
```

Is that monitor you tested it on have a resolution larger than 1600?  If so the div looks like it's limiting the width of your image to 1600.  meaning there will be white space on the right of the image?

Just a thought.